# ajaxStart won't load in Razor Shared page .Net 3.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to load a gif spinner for all AJAX requests in my project and the problem that I am having is that it won't load at all.

Before that, I was including it on certain pages I needed but now I want to put it globally to all of my pages. It was working fine before this new change.

In other views in which I loaded the same piece of javascript, it would function adequately.

At this moment, I am including my `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` methods in a Razor page located in my `Views\Shared\_NavBar_DataUser.cshtml`

If anyone has ever had a similar problem to this one, it would be really appreciating if you would give me some sort of hint on how to resolve this issue.

```
   <nav>
        <div id="divLoading" class="HideLoader">
            <div>
                <img asp-append-version="true" src="~/Content/Img/loading.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Cargar Iframe Tarjeta Especialista -->
    <iframe frameborder="0" src='' name="genericIframe" id="genericIframe" style="display:none;"> 
     </iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let divLoadAjax = window.frames.top.document.getElementById("divLoading") ?? document.getElementById("divLoading");
    console.log(divLoadAjax);
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            let bodyHeight = $(divLoadAjax).closest("body").height();
            $(divLoadAjax).height(bodyHeight * 2); // multiplicamos por 2 para que pueda ocupar todo el espacio de la ventana
            $(divLoadAjax).show();
            let mobileTablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1025px)').matches;
            if (!mobileTablet) {
                let profileNameHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".profile-name")[0].offsetHeight;
                let btnCvDoctorHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-cv-doctor")[0].offsetHeight;
                let specTitleHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-profile")[0].offsetHeight;
                let dayServiceHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".day-service")[0].offsetHeight;
                let buttonReservarMasCitasHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".input-group")[0].offsetHeight;
                let suma = 140 + profileNameHeight + btnCvDoctorHeight + specTitleHeight + dayServiceHeight + buttonReservarMasCitasHeight;
                $("#basicModal").css("height", suma);
            }
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(divLoadAjax).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to put your code into Shared/_Layout.cshtml,and then any page will load the js.
[image]

Page1:
[image]

And I find only when moving `$(document).ajaxStart(function ()` outside `$(document).ready(function ()`,an Ajax request is about to be sent,`$(document).ajaxStart(function ()` will be triggled.

```
<script>
        let divLoadAjax = window.frames.top.document.getElementById("divLoading") ?? document.getElementById("divLoading");
        console.log(divLoadAjax);
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            let bodyHeight = $(divLoadAjax).closest("body").height();
            $(divLoadAjax).height(bodyHeight * 2); // multiplicamos por 2 para que pueda ocupar todo el espacio de la ventana
            $(divLoadAjax).show();
            let mobileTablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1025px)').matches;
            if (!mobileTablet) {
                let profileNameHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".profile-name")[0].offsetHeight;
                let btnCvDoctorHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-cv-doctor")[0].offsetHeight;
                let specTitleHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-profile")[0].offsetHeight;
                let dayServiceHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".day-service")[0].offsetHeight;
                let buttonReservarMasCitasHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".input-group")[0].offsetHeight;
                let suma = 140 + profileNameHeight + btnCvDoctorHeight + specTitleHeight + dayServiceHeight + buttonReservarMasCitasHeight;
                $("#basicModal").css("height", suma);
            }
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(divLoadAjax).hide();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hey there, I will try this also.

Comment: When I put it inside my navbar, it won't work. I don't want to use the Shared/_Layout.cshtml page at all. I am using the navigation bar which is a Shared View. Regardless of that, I am loading the same exact script on the bottom. It detects the divLoadAjax element but it won't enter in the ajaxStart.

Comment: So you move $(document).ajaxStart(function () outside $(document).ready(function (),and still cannot trigger ajaxStart?You need to call an ajax,and then will trigger ajaxStart.

Comment: I am actually doing it in almost all my views which load my Shared View _NavBar_DataUser.cshtml. They all at least have  one AJAX request.